# Crystal Reports User Parameter To Query

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to develop a Crystal Report that passes the user executing the report as a parameter to the report query.

I'm using Business Objects Enterprise, executing the reports through InfoView which I would assume uses the Crystal "Special Fields" Current CE User Name, I just can't figure out how to link that to the query.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way or is this not possible in Crystal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter in the record selection formula. Right click in the report, select "Report -> Selection Formula -> Record...". Then enter a formula - something like this:

```
{my_field_name} = {?my_parameter_name}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's only providing filtering at the Crystal Reports level - not passing a parameter to a database query.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I just checked one of my parameterized reports using sql profiler, and it *did* include the report parameters as a where clause in the query it snet to the db. I don't use InfoView, so maybe that is different, but it seems to me that Crystal would do the same thing since it is way more efficient. I suggest you use the profiler to see what is happening.